# Merging multiple .bak files in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a database named `Bibek`. I have created multiple backups for this database by updating the value of the records present inside the database for different table.

For e.g - `Bibek1.bak`, `Bibek2.bak`, `Bibek3.bak`

Now I want to merge all those `.bak` files to create one single `.bak` file named `BibekFinal` which has all the updates from all the above 3 `.bak` files .

Please help me on this. I am new to SQL Server .

Comment: Just create your final `BibekFinal.bak` from the most recent state of the database - that should contain all the data - no??

Comment: I just gave one example in my question  :) ..

Comment: The SQL Server backup file is always the **whole database** - you're not backing up just a single table at a time. So what are you trying to achieve by *merging* those `.bak` files?? The most recent one is the one that contains all the data - just use that one!